# React onClick spamming queues and fires later?

Tags: reactjs, browser-sync

Unless I'm doing something wrong it appears that the onClick method fires multiple times after I've spammed clicked the button. Like it's queued and debounced somehow.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Button extends React.Component {
  onClick = (e) => {
    console.log('click');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click me fast</button>
    );
  }
}

render(<Button />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

When I click the button times really fast I get this output in the log. The second batch of events (11 click) comes approximately 1 second after the initial bunch.

[image]

Is this intentional from react/jsx, a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thankful for any pointers!

**Update**
This issue only occurs when I'm using BrowserSync

Comment: Which browser`?

Comment: Could be blowing buttermilk here, but perhaps some message on the event queue was injected between one of your button clicks, and the processing of that message took enough time that the following clicks were lumped together in a separate group.

Comment: Seems fine for me - https://codesandbox.io/s/3Z8VVYnA

Comment: Just a side note here, I wouldn't name a function the same as an event handler. It's confusing and bad practise...

Comment: @Chris Agreed. `handleOnClick` is more conventional.

Comment: you have to bind the onClick function. Like this: `<button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Click me fast</button>`   0r better in constructor

Comment: @ArslArsl - this is incorrect or relevant to this question. notice he's using an arrow function for the onClick function, which has a pre-bound lexical scope(fixed "this") - also this will not explain what the poster is asking.

Comment: @MuratK. Tested in Chrome and Safari

Comment: @MisterEpic I think you are right. The problem only occurs when I'm using BrowserSync as the webserver. Not when I'm accessing the .html file directly. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: @Chris Yea, completely agree. Just wrote this fast to replicate the issue I hade in a contained environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was having was more tied to BrowserSync than React. To solve it just disable the "Mirror clicks across devices" in the "Sync options" settings in BrowserSyncs UI view.